# Google Geocode API: same address, different coordinates

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the Google Geocoding API, and I've come to this situation: The same address giving two different Latitude points.

The two strings are(without quotes) :

```
"BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941"  
"BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941"
```

Note that the only difference is the word `ROD` which is replaced by `RODOVIA` (which means Highway). The returned latitudes are, respectively, -19.7507 and -20.2738.

The correct answer is -19.7507. **My question is**: How can I avoid this problem, and what are the possible causes of this API behaviour?

Comment: The Google Maps API doesn't agree that those are the same address.  It gets very different responses.  How are you making the request to the geocoder?  Perhaps localizing it for Brazil (if you can do that) might help.

Comment: I can reproduce those results with `R`. What is more, there are at least two other latitudes. (see community wiki)

Answer (score 0):

```
> coord
         lon       lat                                                                             name
1  -40.39200 -20.27377     BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941
2  -40.37992 -19.75071         BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941
3  -40.37992 -19.75071        BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941
4  -40.43126 -20.28447       BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941
5  -40.39200 -20.27377     BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941
6  -40.37992 -19.75071         BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941
7  -40.37992 -19.75071        BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941
8  -40.43126 -20.28447       BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941
9  -40.39200 -20.27377     BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941
10 -40.37992 -19.75071         BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941
11 -40.37992 -19.75071        BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941
12 -40.39324 -20.28260       BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941
13 -40.39200 -20.27377 BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941
14 -40.37992 -19.75071     BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941
15 -40.37992 -19.75071    BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941
16 -40.43126 -20.28447   BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941
```

#### Code

```
# Language: R
library(ggmaps)
loc <- c("BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281 3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941",
         "BRAZIL CARIACICA PADRE MATHIAS RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS 0KM 281.3 1941",
         "BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, RODOVIA GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, ROD GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, ROD. GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941",
         "BRAZIL, CARIACICA, PADRE MATHIAS, RODOV GOVERNADOR MARIO COVAS, 0KM 281,3 1941") 
coord <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(loc)){
    coord <- rbind(coord, cbind(geocode(loc[i]), name = loc[i]))
}
```

Comment: Alright. I'm doing some tests using the component parameters in the Google Maps API. It seems that the Google algorithms are using some probabilistic interpretations, which, in rare cases like this, is giving poor interpretations.
Thank You